# avoid duplication while updating form using NodeJS and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api

I am a newbie developer I have facing one issue when I try to update a form with fields like username, email, mobile and here email and mobile are unique how can I update this form without duplication by one API request using NodeJS. I am using mongodb as backend.

my mongoose schema is

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    first_name:{
        type:String
    },
    last_name:{
        type:String
    },
    mobile:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        match: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
    },
    bio:{
        type:String
    },
    image:{
        type:String
    },
    
    role:{
        type:String
    },
    status:[{
        type:String,
        default:'inactive'
    }]
},{timestamps:true})

module.exports = mongoose.model('student',studentSchema);
```

my nodejs code is

```
exports.editStudent = async (req, res) => {
  const { first_name, last_name, mobile, email, bio, image } = req.body;

  Student.find(await { $or: [{ email: email }, { mobile: mobile }] })
    .exec()
    .then((result) => {
     if(result.length >=1){

        let errors = {}

        if(user[0].email == email){
            
            errors = 'email exists'

        }else if(user[0].mobile == mobile){

            errors = 'mobile exists'
        }
        res.status(409).json({
            code:409,
            message:errors
        })
        
    } else {
        Student.updateOne(
          { mobile: mobile },
          {
            $set: {
              email: email,
              mobile: mobile,
              first_name: first_name,
              last_name: last_name,
            },
          }
        )
          .exec()
          .then((result) => {
            res.status(201).json({
              code: 201,
              message: "updated",
            });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).json({
              code: 500,
              message: err,
            });
          });
      }
    });
};
```

**Here the problem is when i update email alone it shows mobile exist error**.

please help me if anyone know

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Answers will depend on the framework you use, maybe the database you use, and more.  You'll get the best answers by trying to solve this problem first and then as you run into problems, asking for help when you get stuck in a specific place.

Comment: hi bro i am using nodejs and mongodb as the database.